# Driving a bi-color LED while saving current

Tags: microcontroller, led, gpio

I need to add a LED to my system which uses 1mA on average. The LED shall be connected to a microcontroller GPIO pin which I can set/clear to turn the LED on/off. After looking at the bi-color LED options in Digikey, it seems most LEDs will consume higher current than my system. E.g. the "Current -Test" spec for most LEDs is around 5-20mA. Is there a different way of connecting the LED to my system without using too much current?

For example, one of the LEDs I have been looking at is the: 150080SG54050 (https://www.digikey.co.nz/en/products/detail/w%C3%BCrth-elektronik/150080SG54050/12375466)

Comment: You can drive them at lower currents. They will light up to a few microamps, a pinprick of light though. How bright does it need to be at 1mA?

Comment: You have to decide how much current you will run the LED at using a resistor.

Comment: Red LED can be driven by low current and have enough brightness for indication. Just choose the resistor to set current.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question:

> **Is there a different way** of connecting the LED to my system **without using too much current**?

You also mentioned in the first phrase:

> I need to add a LED to my system **which uses 1mA on average**.

### Limiting LED *Peak* Current

Typically for CPU applications, the current limitation of an LED is done with resistor in series, calculated from the supply voltage minus the V_forward of the LED.
According to your [LED datasheet](https://www.we-online.com/catalog/datasheet/150080SG54050.pdf), for I=20mA:
V_f (Red) = 2.0V
V_f (Green) = 3.3V
So, for a selected current of let’s say 10mA, and assuming V_f is constant (which is Not over a large current range - here it is assumed constant just for simplicity), we have for Vbat= 5.0 and Red LED, as:

- R(red)   = (5.0 - 2.0)/0.01 = 300R(Ohm); and
- R(green) = (5.0 - 3.3)/0.01 = 170R(Ohm).

Or approximate commercial values.
Observe I assumed as negligible V_drop of a saturated Mosfet (or CPU port), but the saturation of a bipolar transistor could be Vce ~= 0.4V, being further deducted in the above voltage differential values.
The central point here is to show *how to calculate R* for each element of the bicolor LED, and for a given *peak/instantaneous current*.

### Limiting LED *Average* Current

The **perceived brightness** by human eye is greatly influenced by the *PEAK luminosity*, not much the average value.
On the other hand, battery consumption and operating life are all about AVERAGE consumption.
The trick is to drive the LED - whatever color you decide to use - with short pulses, let’s say of 10mA, but with a small duty cycle.  For instance, 5% On and 95% Off; in this case, the average current becomes just 5% of 10mA = 0.5mA.

If the oscillator (e.g. PWM) FREQUENCY is larger than 100 Hz, human eye persistence will not detect the LED working in pulsating mode, and it will appear as continuously lit.
If you wish to make it more visible, then Turn/Blink On-Off that 100Hz oscillator with another lower frequency oscillator, for instance @ 1Hz.
In this case, **with blinking PWM-driven LED you get some additional features**:

- User will more easily notice if the LED is On (blinking) or Off.
- Current consumption will be proportionally lower: assuming 50% blink ratio, I_avg = 50% (0.5mA) = 0.25mA.
- You could drive both LEDs, creating different color coding, and still have a lower *overall average* consumption.

### Controlled LED Overdrive

This General recipe *has been used even for some overdrive* (above 20mA nominal), if peak/instantaneous current is respected, and duty cupcake is little.
For your specific LED:
Max peak current (@ 10% 1KHz) < 40 mA (see datasheet).

Overall power dissipation of the LED should not the overcome too.
Please also consider that you **may need to (over)drive** each set of “Resistor+LED” with a **Bipolar or Mosfet transistor** (+ limiting/polarization resistors on Base/Gate), as most CPU ports work well up to 10mA, and 20mA max.
But on doing this “controlled” overdrive, peak current produces peak brightness (and visual feedback), while with tiny duty cycles, average current is still battery minded.

Bottomline: even a small LED with manageable average consumption can provide a flashy feedback.

Answer (score 2):

The "test current" is simply the current at which the LED is characterized: its luminous intensity, forward voltage, spectral bandwith, etc.  There's nothing that says you can't put less current through it, only the characteristics might change a bit.  From the graphs on page 4 of your datasheet, it looks like you should get acceptable performance from less than 5mA, depending on how bright you're expecting the indicator to be.  If efficiency is your goal, you could also use a lower value resistor (for, say, 20mA If) and pulse the GPIO pin to control brightness to an acceptable level.

Comment: Would using a MOSFET make a difference in this case? I'm not familiar with these but the system is intended to run off a battery for several months.

Comment: @user1397215 run LED from battery for several months even 1mA is too much. Impulse mode should be used.

Comment: If you just need an indication that the device is operating, you can flash the LED with a 5 mA pulse of about 100 mSec, every 10 seconds or so, like the indicator on a smoke alarm. That duty cycle (1%) would be equivalent to a continuous draw of 50 uA.